# how do I extract the right type from my pseduo-union type

Tags: scala.js

I have a psuedo union type returned from a js.

Here's my scalajs:

```
    @js.native
    trait ErrorResponse extends js.Object {
      val error: String = js.native
      val errorDescription: String = js.native
    }

    @js.native
    trait TokenResponse extends js.Object{
      val accessToken: String = js.native
      val expriseOn: js.Date = js.native
      val tokenType: String = js.native
      val userId: String = js.native
      val identityProvider: String = js.native
    }
```

and my scalajs

```
    @js.native
    @JSImport("mymodule", "JSClassInModule")
    class JSClassInModule extends js.Object {
      // ...
      def scalajsfunc(): ErrorResponse | TokenResponse = js.native
      // ..
    }
```

If I call scalajsfunc, how do I idiomatically boil down the returned value to one of the two classes specified in my pseudo-union class?

Answer (score 6):

Use pattern matching:

```scala
val jsClassInModule: JSClassInModule = ???
(jsClassInModule.scalajsfunc(): Any) match {
  case response: ErrorResponse => ...
  case response: TokenResponse => ...
}
```

The ascription `: Any` is necessary to work around the fact that the Scala type checker does not know about the specific semantics of `|`, and gives spurious error messages if you try to directly match on a `|`.

**Edit:** If the individual types are *JS traits*, i.e., traits that extend `js.Any`, the above will not work, as in general it is not possible to perform `isInstanceOf` tests with JS traits (which is what pattern matching does, and is mostly unrelated to `|`). Instead, you need to code up whatever instance test makes sense, then cast. For example, assuming we can tell an `ErrorResponse` from a `TokenResponse` by testing for the existence of an `errorCode` property, we could do:

```scala
val jsClassInModule: JSClassInModule = ???
(jsClassInModule.scalajsfunc(): Any) match {
  case response if js.Object.hasOwnProperty(response, "errorCode") =>
    val errorResponse = response.asInstanceOf[ErrorResponse]
    ...
  case response =>
    val tokenResponse = response.asInstanceOf[TokenResponse]
    ...
}
```

Such is the ugly nature of JavaScript.

Comment: That did not seem to work. Each case clause says: "not supported because it is a raw JS trait". I'm not sure how it would determine this anyway given that the only difference in the objects are some attributes which may or may not be defined...both sides of the | are js.Objects.

Comment: Oh, that's another thing that's mostly unrelated to `|`. There is indeed nothing the Scala.js compiler could do to test whether an object is an instance of a JS trait. In that case, you have to code the test yourself, and then cast. See my updated answer.

Comment: That seems to do it. I had to adjust the if test to response.merge[js.Object].hasProperty("error")